# Does the term "monad" apply to values of types like Maybe or List, or does it instead apply only to the types themselves?

Tags: terminology, monads

I've noticed that the word "monad" seems to be used in a somewhat inconsistent way. I've come to believe that this is because many (if not most) of the monad tutorials out there are written by folks who have only just started to figure monads out themselves (eg: nuclear waste spacesuit burritos), and so the term ends up getting kind of overloaded/corrupted.

In particular, I'm wondering whether the term "monad" can be applied to individual values of types like Maybe, List or IO, or if the term "monad" should really only be applied to the types themselves.

This is a subtle distinction, so perhaps an analogy might make it more clear. In mathematics we have, rings, fields, groups, etc. These terms apply to an entire set of values along with the operations that can be performed on them, rather than to individual elements. For example, integers (along with the operations of addition, negation and multiplication) form a ring. You could say "Integer is a ring", but you would never say "5 is a ring".

So, can you say "`Just 5` is a monad", or would that be as wrong as saying "5 is a ring"? I don't know category theory, but I'm under the impression that it really only makes sense to say "`Maybe` is a monad" and not "`Just 5` is a monad".

Comment: Read about category theory if you know some algebra. It may even interest you.

Comment: @AlexandreC. I've read a bit about category theory, though have yet to find a good introduction. Any suggestions? The Wikipedia pages on the subject seem to be written with the assumption that the reader already understands category theory. One thing in particular that confuses me is the statement that categories have "a collection of objects". What is a "collection"? A set? Something else?

Comment: The problem with CT is that it is so abstract that you have to bring your own examples with you. You'll find working knownledge in any good introductory course on algebraic geometry (or commutative algebra), some computer science courses, some geometry courses, etc. [This](http://wwwhome.cs.utwente.nl/~fokkinga/mmf92b.html) seems promising for the computer science point of view. The standard book is MacLane's *Category Theory for the Working Mathematician*. Also, read [Sigfpe's blog](http://blog.sigfpe.com/)

Comment: Also don't worry about the set theoretic issues. There are 3 ways to deal with them: 1) pretend they don't exist 2) Pick a big enough set (a "universe") and restrict yourself to elements of the universe (the Grothendieck approach) 3) Rewrite set theory such that a) category theory comes first b) axiomatize the category of sets (the Lawvere approach). I tend to stick with 1, and knowing that 3 exists fulfills me.

Comment: [I wrote about this same problem a couple of years ago.](http://blog.plover.com/prog/haskell/monad-terminology.html) I suggested that the values of monadic types could be called "motes".

Comment: Note that there is yet another level of confusion that can occur here. You're right to say `Just 5` is not a monad, and that `Maybe` is. But it's also important to point out that the type of `Just 5`, `Maybe Integer`, is also not a Monad.

Comment: @MarkDominus I was actually considering writing a follow-up question asking what the values of monadic types are called. As you mention in your post, "monadic value" is quite a mouthful.

Answer (score 11, accepted):

`List` is a monad, `List a` is a type, and `[]` is a `List a` (an element of a type).

Technically, a monad is a *functor* with extra structure; and in Haskell we only use functors from the category of Haskell types to itself.

It is thus in particular a "function" which takes a type and returns another type (it has kind `* -> *`).

`List`, `State s`, `Maybe`, etc are monads. `State` is not a monad, since it has kind `* -> * -> *`.

*(aside: to confuse matters, Monads are just functors, and if I give myself a partially ordered set A, then it forms a category, with Hom(a, b) = { 1 element } if a <= b and Hom(a, b) = empty otherwise. Now any increasing function f : A -> A forms a functor, and monads are those functions which satisfy x <= f(x) and f(f(x)) <= f(x), hence f(f(x)) = f(x) -- monads here are technically "elements of A -> A". See also [closure operators](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Closure_operator).)*

*(aside 2: since you appear to know some mathematics, I encourage you to read about category theory. You'll see among others that algebraic structures can be seen as arising from monads. See [this excellent blog entry from the excellent blog by Dan Piponi](http://blog.sigfpe.com/2007/02/monads-for-vector-spaces-probability.html) for a teaser.)*

Comment: Interesting. So is `State` a monad, or is `State s` a monad?

Comment: @LaurenceGonsalves: `State s` is a monad. `State` has kind `* -> * -> *`.

Answer (score 19):

"Monad" (and "Functor") are popularly *misused* as describing values.
No value is a monad, functor, monoid, applicative functor, etc.
Only types & type constructors (higher-kinded types) can be.
When you hear (and you will) that "lists are monoids" or "functions are monads", etc, or "this function takes a monad as an argument", don't believe it.
Ask the speaker "How can any value be a monoid (or monad or ...), considering that Haskells classes classify *types* (including higher-order ones) rather than values?"
Lists are not monoids (etc). `List a` is.

My guess is that this popular misuse stems from mainstream languages having value classes and not type classes, so that habitual, unconscious value-class thinking sneaks in.

Why does it matter whether we use language precisely?
Because we think in language and we build & convey understandings via language.
So in order to have clear thoughts, it helps to have clear language (or be able to at any time).

"The slovenliness of our language makes it easier for us to have foolish thoughts. The point is that the process is reversible." - George Orwell, Politics and the English Language

*Edit:* These remarks apply to Haskell, not to the more general setting of category theory.

Comment: Is it ok to say "lists *give rise to* a monoid"?

Comment: It would be even more precise that there *exists* a monoid/monad/whatever with List as its carrier, since there are in general many such algebraic structures over the same carrier.

Comment: @MauricioScheffer I'd simply say "`List a` is a monoid" (for all `a`) and "`List` is a functor/applicative/monad".

Comment: "Why does it matter whether we use language precisely?" I completely agree, and that's why I'm asking this question. The inconsistent (and usually incorrect) use of the term monad I think has been the source of a lot of my confusion, and probably the confusion of others.

Comment: Regarding "No value is a monad ... Only types & type constructors (higher-kinded types) can be.", please see Alexandre C.'s (first) aside in his answer where he describes a category which is a partially ordered set, and then goes on to state "monads are those functions which satisfy...". I'm pretty new to this category theory stuff, but I think your statement is only true when restricted to "the category of Haskell types", and when talking about categories where the objects are actually values, then you could have functions which are monads (or other kinds of functors). Does that sound right?

Comment: Re: "mainstream languages having value classes and not type clases, so that habitual, unconscious value-class thinking sneaks in." I'm also pretty new to Haskell, and this is actually one thing that I'm not sure about. Is there something that "type classes" do that generic (ie: parameterized) abstract classes in other languages don't do? Are they more powerful/expressive? It almost seems to me that the difference is just convention: classes in Haskell (at least some) are named like algebraic structures, while in OO languages they are named in a way that applies to the values.

Comment: "... when talking about categories where the objects are actually values, then you could have functions which are monads (or other kinds of functors). Does that sound right?" Yes. I interpreted your question as being about Haskell's notion of Monad.

Comment: @MauricioScheffer: If you say "lists give rise to a monoid", I might ask which lists (values) you have in mind---some? all? Also, "give rise to" is unnecessarily vague.

Answer (score 4):

To be exact, monads are structures from category theory.  They don't have a direct code counterpart.  For simplicity let's talk about general functors instead of monads.  In the case of Haskell roughly speaking a functor is a mapping from a class of types to a class of types that also maps functions in the first class to functions in the second.  The `Functor` instance gives you access to the mapping function, but doesn't directly capture the concept of functors.

It is however fair to say that the type constructor as mentioned in the `Functor` instance is the actual functor:

```
instance Functor Tree
```

In this case `Tree` is the functor.  However, because `Tree` is a type constructor it can't stand for both mapping functions that make a functor at the same time.  The function that maps functions is called `fmap`.  So if you want to be precise you have to say that the tuple `(Tree, fmap)` is the functor, where `fmap` is the particular `fmap` from `Tree`'s `Functor` instance.  For convenience, again, we say that `Tree` is the functor, because the corresponding `fmap` follows from its `Functor` instance.

Note that functors are always types of kind `* -> *`.  So `Maybe Int` is not a functor – the functor is `Maybe`.  Also people often talk about "the state monad", which is also imprecise.  `State` is a whole family of infinitely many state monads, as you can see in the instance:

```
instance Monad (State s)
```

For every type `s` the type constructor `State s` (of kind `* -> *`) is *a* state monad, one of many.

Answer (score 2):

> So, can you say "Just 5 is a monad", or would that be as wrong as saying "5 is a ring"?

Your intuition is exactly right. `Int` is to `Ring` (or `AbelianGroup` or whatever) as `Maybe` is to `Monad` (or `Functor` or whatever). Values (`5`, `Just 5`, etc.) are unimportant.

In algebra, we say the set of integers *form* a ring; in Haskell we would say (informally) that `Int` is a member of the `Ring` typeclass, or (slightly more formally) that there exists a `Ring` instance for `Int`. You might find [this proposal](http://hackage.haskell.org/trac/haskell-prime/wiki/NumericClasses) fun and/or useful. Anyway, same deal with monads.

> I don't know category theory, but ...

Whatever, if you know a thing or two about abstract algebra, you're golden.

Answer (score 1):

I would say "Just 5 is of a type that is an instance of a Monad" like i would say "5 is a number that has type (Integer) is a ring".

I use the term instance because is how in Haskell you declare an implementation of a typeclass, and Monad is one of them.

Comment: Ok, it sounds like you agree that "monad" is a term that applies to the type, and not to the individual values of that type. I avoided using the term "instance" in my question because while Haskell uses it to refer to types (eg: the type Maybe is an instance of the Monad typeclass) many (most?) programmers use "instance" to refer to the values of the type. I think this may actually be part of the reason so many things that talk about monads are confused about this issue.

Comment: Yes, Monad is absolutely on the type, because the bind operator work with a type, the value you supply is just something of that monad type. This way the compiler is sure that the specific Monad instance methods can be safely applied to that value. BTW if you are satisfied with the answer, could you please accept it? Thanks!

Comment: I was with you up until that last comment. "... the bind operator work with a type, the value you supply is just something of that monad type. This way the compiler is sure that the specific Monad instance methods can be safely applied to that value." is all irrelevant to terminology. Take for example "Collection" and "List".  In some languages these are both types, and List is a subtype of Collection. So any operation you can perform on a Collection can be performed on a List (eg: finding out its size) and this is all statically type safe. However, a value of the List type is a Collection.

Comment: Really? I cannot understand: please post an example of inheritance in Haskell, which is what you are talking about I think...

Comment: I'm not talking about Haskell specifically. I'm talking about general terminology. (I did have the Haskell tag on this question for a while, but that was actually after you made that comment.)

Comment: I think you're illustrating the very confusion the question is about. `Just 5` is (or at least might be, depending on context) of type `Maybe Integer`. This is not an instance of `Monad`, though `Maybe` is an instance of `Monad`.

Comment: @VincenzoMaggio you have a kind error. Monads have kind `* -> *`, which are not types, but rather *type constructors*.

Comment: @mergeconflict Not necessarily a kind error. From what I've seen over the last 25 years or so, the term "type" is also widely used to include what you're calling "type constructors", as in the phrase ["higher-kinded types"](https://www.google.com/search?q="higher+kinded+types").